# Return a utf-8 string with HttpEncoder.HtmlDecode?

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding

I am trying to write a method in C# that takes a string with HTML encoded characters and returns it as utf-8 characters.  At first I thought this was already possible with the [HttpEncoder.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.util.httpencoder.htmldecode.aspx) method but this returns void and takes TextWriter for output as the second param.  I don't really get the TextWriter class.  How can I wrap this so that it takes and returns strings?  Or is there a batter way?

e.g.

```
myHTMLDecode("Tania P&eacute;rez-Salas Compa&ntilde;ia de Danza")
```

would return the utf-8 string - Tania Pérez-Salas Compañia de Danza

**edit** - The other problem I am having is that HttpEncoder.HtmlDecode is a protected method.  Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) which takes a string and retruns a string. HttpEncoder.HtmlDecode seems to be internal according to the page I linked which I would have thought would make it a pain to use...

Answer (score 3):

Use a StringWriter

```
public static String DecodeHtmlEntities(String s) {
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    HttpEncoder.HtmlDecode(s, writer);
    return writer.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This looks like it would work, however I now realize that the method is marked "protected internal virtual" so I get: "Error 'System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.HtmlDecode' is inaccessible due to its protection level"